# Python pickle loses data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pickle

I have 4 nested classes, see example:

```
class GameInfo:
    id = ""
    round = ""
    # ... etc

class Opponent:
    game_info = GameInfo()
    name = ""
    # ...

class Tournament:
    opponent_list = [] # list of Opponent objects
    # ...

class Journal(db.Model):
    picked_tournament = db.BlobProperty()  # here I put picked Tournament object
```

the problem is: when I unpickle `pickled_tournament` in `Journal` all data from `GameInfo` is lost. I.e. `opponent.name` shows correct value, but `opponent.game_info.id` shows empty string.

I use Google App Engine datastore to store data and `picked_tournament` is stored in BlobProperty(). To serialize data I invoke: `journal.picked_tournament = pickle.dumps(tournament)`. To load data I use: `tournament = pickle.loads(journal.picked_tournament)`

Why pickle is not going deeper than 2 levels?

UPD: data is set as follows:

```
gi = GameInfo()
gi.id = "1234"
opp = Opponent()
opp.name = "John"
opp.game_info = gi
t = Tournament()
t.opponent_list.append(opp)
# etc...
```

UPD2: just discovered that everything works fine on development server if database is sqlite3, but does not work without sqlite3 and on appspot!

Comment: you don't show us where and how you set game_info.id

Comment: @systempuntoout game_info.id is set naturally, see update

Comment: Have you tried unpickling the Tournament pickle directly without going via Journal.picked_tournament (which is a db.BlobProperty)? That might help you isolate the issue (could be a BlobProperty thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor for your `Opponent` class, you instantiate a single copy of `GameInfo`, which is used by all the instances of that class. For example:

```
>>> o1 = Opponent()
>>> o1.game_info.id = 5
>>> o2 = Opponent()
>>> o2.game_info.id
5
```

Instead, you need to create one for each Opponent instance. Do this by initializing it in the constructor, like this:

```
class Opponent:
    def __init__(self):
        game_info = GameInfo()
```

Also, since it's not the 1990s, you really should be using [new style classes](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/node33.html).

Comment: the problem is gone once I move initialization of game_info into constructor of Opponent (figured out by myself, but thank you for clearing it out in the question)

Answer (score 1):

Based on App Engine documentation (I haven't tried it in practice), try setting the pickle data as a blob:

```
journal.picked_tournament = db.Blob(pickle.dumps(tournament))
```

If this doesn't work, verify that journal.picked_tournament == pickle.dumps(tournament).